# Recreate absolute button placement with responsive design

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem recreating this design from an absolute placement to a "relative" or responsive design. It is kind of like a flower with the core (logo or button) in the middle and petals (more buttons) surrounding it. I needed to make this design and since I was just using my monitor, it was fine but now that other people will be looking at it with different sized monitors I wanted it so the petals will stay the same distance relative to the core and the core will stay relative to the center of the div.

Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o0a0Lv4a/

Here is the CSS also:

```
.button {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: right;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}
.button.big-btn {
    width: 90px;
    height: 40px;
}

.button1{
    position: absolute;
    left: 225px;
    top: 15px;
}
.button2{
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 45px;
}
.button3{
    position: absolute;
    left: 350px;
    top: 45px;
}.button4{
    position: absolute;
    left: 225px;
    top: 90px;
}
.button5{
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 125px;
}
.button6{
    position: absolute;
    left: 350px;
    top: 125px;
}
.button7{
    position: absolute;
    left: 225px;
    top: 175px;
}
```

I've also tried doing "display: block; max-width:100%" which is great for resizing the buttons, but does not help with moving them.

[image]

Comment: Hard to visualise from your description. Attach two mockups, so we can see the behaviour you are talking about

Comment: Thinking relative, px probably won't work as well as percentages. I'd also think about using transforms & transform origin.

Comment: @tmslnz here is a screenshot from the JSFIddle, I'll also edit the post: https://i.imgur.com/wjuQEbS.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `flexbox` and a few markup changes

```css
.wrap, .col {
  display: flex;
}
.wrap .col {
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.button {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.button.big-btn {
  width: 90px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="button big-btn button1">Button 1</div>
    <div class="button big-btn button2">Button 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="button big-btn button3">Button 3</div>
    <div class="button big-btn button4">Button 4</div>
    <div class="button big-btn button5">Button 5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="button big-btn button6">Button 6</div>
    <div class="button big-btn button7">Button 7</div>
  </div>
</div>
```